# AutoLayoutでViewの下部とViewの上部を合わせる方法

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

画像のように、ImageViewの下部に灰色のViewの上部を合わせたいです。どのように指定すれば良いでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

（回答者補筆） 
ImageViewの高さは固定、灰色のViewの高さは、フレキシブル（画面の大きさによって可変）です。

Comment: ImageViewの高さは固定、灰色のViewの高さは、フレキシブル（画面の大きさによって可変）ということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: その通りです。ImageViewは横幅:縦幅=10:3になるように設定してあります。説明が足らず申し訳ありません。

Comment: 質問文を加筆しました。今後質問なさる時は、気づいたらご自身で質問文を、より完成したものに編集するよう、心がけていただけたらと思います。

Comment: 何かと至らず申し訳ありません！承知しました。ご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoLayoutの基本は、Constraint（制約）をViewに加えるという操作です。Constraintは、Viewの位置と大きさが、一意に決まるように設定します。不足しても、多すぎてもXcodeから警告が出ます。
もっとも頻度の高いConstraintは、このケースでしょう。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

①左（あるいは右）方向のオブジェクトに対する間隔。②上（あるいは下）方向のオブジェクトに対する間隔。③Viewの幅。④Viewの高さ。
4つのConstraintを、Storyboard上で、このように指定します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

マウスクリックで、破線を実線に変えたり、チェックを入れて、最後に「Add 4 Constraints」ボタンを押します。

ViewのConstraintは、いちばん近くにあるオブジェクトに対するものになります。Viewの左側に別のViewが存在すれば、左側のConstraintは、そのViewとの間隔になります。左側に別のViewがなければ、親Viewの左エッジが、Constraintの対象のオブジェクトとなります。

次に、Viewの横幅が、他のオブジェクトとの関係によって、フレキシブルに変化するConstraintを考えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Viewの横幅は、親Viewの横幅が変化すると、一緒に変化します。
これは、このように設定します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Widthのチェックを外して、代わりに右側の破線をクリックして、実線に変えます。
幅も高さも、他のオブジェクトに対してフレキシブルにするのは、先の応用です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Width、Height両方のチェックを外して、四囲すべて実線にします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]